# Camera App - Create new album with PHPhotoLibrary with .addOnly PHAccessLevel

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a camera app which takes pictures with iPhone cameras and saves it to the cameraRoll. It requires me to ask for PHPhotoLibrary PHAccessLevel as .addOnly.
An app should save pictures to specific Album - what forces me to check if album exists and to create one if not.

```
//Create variable that will store Album name
let albumName = "AppName"
var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!
```

```
//Functions that checks if album with specific name exists and saves it to assetCollection variable

if let assetCollection = fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() {
    self.assetCollection = assetCollection
    return
}

func fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() -> PHAssetCollection? {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)
        let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)

        if let _: AnyObject = collection.firstObject {
            return collection.firstObject
        }
        return nil
    }
```

```
//Create album if doesn't exists
func createAlbum() {
        if assetCollection == nil {
        //If assetCollection is empty (album doesn't exist), create one
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: albumName)   // create an asset collection with the album name
            }) { success, error in
                if success {
                    self.assetCollection = self.fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum()
                } else {
                    //With PHAccessLevel as .addOnly error describes that .readWrite access required
                    print("error \(String(describing: error))")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that above functions requires full access to users photoLibrary. Is there a way to handle album creation without asking for full .readWrite PHAccessLevel?

Comment: No, there isn't. That is exactly the distinction between the two types of authorization, as you already know. Is this a real question?

Comment: Yes, its my real question :). No problem at all to force users to grant full library access, just wanted to limit permissions as much as possible.